# How long and how much is each contract of the four main NBA on TNT hosts?

Tags: trivia, nba, finances, media

What is the length and amount of each of the following's contract with TNT?

Charles Barkley

Kenny Smith

Ernie Johnson

Shaquille O'Neal

Answer (score 6):

This is taken from various websites, so anyone is free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Charles Barkley: $1 million/year and has been with TNT for 13 years and his contract is due to expire in 2018.

Kenny Smith: $1 million/year

Ernie Johnson (host): $2.7 million/year

Shaquille O'Neal: $1 million/year

Sources: [Charles Barkley](http://www.sportingnews.com/nba/story/2012-11-05/charles-barkley-tnt-contract-inside-the-nba-open-court-shaquille-oneal-chris-web), [Contracts](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_much_money_does_ernie_Johnson_make_as_a_tnt_analyst), [Extention](http://www.insidehoops.com/blog/?p=580)